# Antialias is drawing an extra line when setNeedsDisplayInRect is called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quartz-graphics

The following code is drawing an extra line when the mouse is pressed over the view. It seems to be cause by antialias. Has anyone seen this before?

[Sample Image](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1silfcjqn5rvx6d/YMKqfQc1F-/Sample.jpg)

```
- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);


    [[NSColor blueColor] setStroke];

    NSBezierPath *path1 = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path1 moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(0.00, 9.00)];
    [path1 lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(300.00, 8.00)];
    [path1 stroke];


    [[NSColor redColor] setStroke];

    NSBezierPath *path2 = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path2 moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(184.00, 15.00)];
    [path2 lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(8.00, 159.00)];
    [path2 stroke];
}

- (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];

    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 369, 15)];
}
```

Comment: When you say "extra line" what do you mean? Can you provide an image?

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question. Since I'm a new user, I cannot post images. Here's a link to a sample image. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1silfcjqn5rvx6d/YMKqfQc1F-/Sample.jpg

Comment: You're drawing two lines in your code... How is one "extra"?

Comment: I'm seeing this issue in multiple applications. Including Apple Sketch sample. I'm using OS 10.7.4, Xcode 4.3.3.

Comment: After clicking the view, a third line is drawn. Sample: https://dropbox.com/sh/1silfcjqn5rvx6d/YMKqfQc1F-/Sample.jpg